# How to prove that Cantor ternary set has no intervals using ternary expansions?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, cantor-set, ternary-expansion

Found this proof on this site: [Cantor's Set Has No Intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483310/cantors-set-has-no-intervals/483353#483353) but I don't understand a part of it.

Here is the proof:

Suppose that $x,y\in C$, where

$$x=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{a_k}{3^k}\quad\text{and}\quad y=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{b_k}{3^k}\;,$$

where all $a_k,b_k\in\{0,2\}$. Let $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ be minimal such that $a_n\ne b_n$, and without loss of generality assume that $a_n=0$ and $b_n=2$. Define $c_k=a_k=b_k$ for $k=1,\dots,n-1$ and $c_k=1$ for $k\ge n$, and let $$z=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{c_k}{3^k}\;;$$ then $x<z<y$, and $z\notin C$.

So what makes $x<z<y$ ? 
I got that that first $n-1$ the terms are equal in $x,y,z$ and at $k=n$
we have $x_n= 0$, $y_n = \dfrac{2}{3^n}$ and $z_n =\dfrac{1}{3^n}$

So,

$\sum_{k\ge 1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{3^k} < \sum_{k\ge 1}^{n}\frac{c_k}{3^k}
 < \sum_{k\ge 1}^{n}\frac{b_k}{3^k}$

but for the terms whose indices is $k$ where $k=n+1,n+2,...$ what guarantees that still $x<z<y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_k}{3^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{b_k}{3^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{c_k}{3^k}$. The largest possible value of $x$ occurs when $a_k=2$ for all $k>n$. In that case

$$x=u+\frac{a_n}{3^n}+\sum_{k>n}\frac2{3^k}=u+0+\frac{\frac2{3^{n+1}}}{1-\frac13}=u+\frac1{3^n}\;.$$

The smallest possible value of $y$ occurs when $b_k=0$ for all $k>n$. In that case

$$y=u+\frac{b_n}{3^n}=u+\frac2{3^n}+\sum_{k>n}\frac0{3^n}=u+\frac2{3^n}\;.$$

Finally,

$$z=u+\frac{c_n}{3^n}+\sum_{k>n}\frac{c_k}{3^k}=u+\sum_{k\ge n}\frac1{3^k}=u+\frac{\frac1{3^n}}{1-\frac13}=u+\frac32\cdot\frac1{3^n}\;.$$

Clearly

$$u+\frac1{3^n}<u+\frac32\cdot\frac1{3^n}<u+\frac2{3^n}\;,$$

i.e., $x<z<y$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Dreamer123: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. You have been doing this for a long time, just in base 10 instead of base 3. That is, I'm sure you'll think it's obvious that 
$$
0.11<0.114595578<0.12.
$$
That's exactly what's happening here:
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{c_k}{3^n}<\frac2{3^n}
$$
no matter the values of $c_k\in\{0,1,2\}$. For a formal proof,
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{c_k}{3^n}\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^n}=2\frac{\tfrac{1}{3^{n+1}}}{1-\tfrac13}=\frac1{3^n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$z$ is between $x$ and $y$ because the $n$-th term dominates:  it is larger than or equal to the sum of all the remaining terms.  That is, for instance, $0.012222222222\lt0.02$, and so on for any length tail of $2$'s.

Recall  $0.122222222\dots=0.2$.

Just look at the geometric series $\sum(2/3)^n=3$.  And remember it's an increasing sequence.

This is, I believe, basic *numerical analysis*.