# Prove the Cantor set doesn't contain any open interval

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

Need to prove that $C=\{ \sum _{k=1}^\infty \frac {a_k}{3^k} ; a_k \in \{0,2\}\}$ doesn't contain any open interval and I am not sure how to begin.
Thank you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483310/cantors-set-has-no-intervals

Comment: Can prove that it has measure $0$?

Comment: In particular, proof in terms of ternary expansion is in the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/483342/442